# How to get list stock from Yahoo finance

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

I wanna to get list stock (symbols) from Yahoo finances as Json file based on site http://finance.yahoo.com/stock-center/ . Please look at "market mover", I wanna to get all data. I have searched and trying to download some file but I have not find JSON file yet. Please kindly help me. Thank you so much.